# where is chessbase support located?

Tags: chessbase

I asked how to fix a problem in chessbase.
And was told to ask chessbase support.

I can not find any support for chessbase.

Where can I find support to fix the problems with chessbase?

Comment: The name of the site is mentioned so many times this reads like an attempt at SEO. The title of the question into google takes you straight to the correct answer on the official site. This feels like it's not even a real question and should be deleted

Answer (score 2):

I believe they mean to make a request at their support site here: https://en.chessbase.com/support-new